# Undo a merge in git and reconstruct the state using rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Let's say I have this graph:

```
A - B -  C1.1 -  D - E - F -G (master)
       \_ C2.1 _/(feature)
```

And I want to undo the merge, add something like C1.2 to the master branch and then remerge and apply D,E,F,G. I know that usually the way is to revert the merge with the -m1 flag and then revert the revert commit when we want to remerge **(let's suppose that we do not want to cherry-pick E,F,G, because maybe there are much more commits after the merge)**. The question is:

Why this:

```
$ git resset --hard C1.1
$ git commit C1.2 # New commits here
$ git merge feature
$ git rebase G E --onto master
```

Is not working to solve the situation? To be clear, "solving the situation" is having something like this graph (although with different SHA values for the commits but with the same content):

```
A - B -  C1.1 - C1.2  - D - E - F -G (master)
       \_ _ _ C2.1 _ _ _/(feature)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before all else, let's be sure we're clear about commit identity.  (Your post suggests you're aware of this, but your diagrams are misleading.)  If you rebase, you are creating new commits, and at most the branch you rebase will point through the new commit.  (If you don't use a branch ref for the rebase, then only HEAD will end up referring to the new commits, which are essentially temporary unless you then tag or branch to give them a ref.)

Let's step through your procedure.  We have

```
A - B - C1.1 - D - E - F -G <--(master)
      \      /
        C2.1 <--(feature)
```

So I assume you're on `master`, and you say

```
git resset --hard C1.1
```

which gives us

```
A - B - C1.1 <--(master)
     \       \
      \        D - E - F -G
       \     /
         C2.1 <--(feature)
```

Notice that `D` through `G` are still out there (in fact your later commands depend on it).  Then you do some new commits

```
git commit #c1.2
```

gives

```
A - B - C1.1 - C1.2 <--(master)
     \       \
      \        D - E - F -G
       \     /
         C2.1 <--(feature)
```

Now you re-merge feature.

```
git merge feature
```

This is the first place where you're creating a new commit, but your diagrams suggest you may think you're somehow "reusing" an old one.  You really have

```
A - B - C1.1 - C1.2 ------------ D' <--(master)
     \       \                  /
      \        D - E - F -G    /
       \     /                /
         C2.1 --------------- 
            ^--(feature)
```

Next your rebase syntax is wrong.  The upstream goes before the commit reference (which is usually a branch), and I *think* the `--onto` may have to go before either of them.  Also, the upstream would be the last commit *not* rebased, so you would really want something like

```
git rebase --onto master D G
```

which gives

```
                                   E' - F' - G' <--()
                                  /                 ^HEAD
A - B - C1.1 - C1.2 ------------ D' <--(master)
     \       \                  /
      \        D - E - F -G    /
       \     /                /
         C2.1 --------------- 
            ^--(feature)
```

Note that this doesn't update the `master` ref, so next you'd need to do something like

```
git branch -f master
```

From here on I'll omit the original `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G`, but they're still there.  In particular they're still in the remote (assuming you have a remote) and would still be reachable from the remote's version of `master`.  This means that to push, you'll have to "force push", and this will put the repo in a problem state for any other developers.  See "recovering from upstream rebase" in the git rebase documentation for details; if this still seems like a good idea, the push command would be `git push -f`.  At that point, we no longer care about the old commits and can assume they'll eventually be discarded by gc.

So our graph would be

```
A - B - C1.1 - C1.2 - D' - E' - F' - G' <--(master)
     \               /
      C2.1 ----------
         ^--(feature)
```

The `D'`...`G'` are new commits; any tags will not have been carried over, any other branches would still point through the old ones, and the SHA1 values (commit ID) will have changed.  This is unavoidable when you rewrite history because of the way git stores data.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, I would:

- Go back to C1.1, cherry-pick C2.1, then cherry-pick E, F and G:

`git checkout C1.1
git cherry-pick C2.1
git cherry-pick D..G # D won't be applied so it's all fine`

Comment: In the question I stated that "let's suppose that we do not want to cherry-pick E,F,G, because maybe there are much more commits after the merge". I will edit the question to highlight that requisition.

Comment: Ok... I didn't get it right. :-) But then, why do you want to use rebase and _not_ cherry-pick if, actually, rebase uses cherry-pick behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0):

Having read what the options mean from the rebase command you issue, I think the problem is that you say *git rebase **G E** --onto master* and I think it should be `git rebase D G --onto master` so that D is actually not applied and it goes from there up to G (in other words, applying E, F and G). At least, that's what I got from reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase